# PHP function returning true/false returns NULL

Tags: php

Without the excess code I have a function that deletes directories:

```
<?php
function delete_directory($dir)
{
 if (is_dir($dir))
 {
  $objects = scandir($dir);

  foreach ($objects as $object)
  {
   if (!in_array($object,array('.','..')))
   {
    if (filetype($dir.'/'.$object) == 'dir') {dir_del($dir.'/'.$object);}
    else {unlink($dir.'/'.$object);}
   }
  }

  reset($objects);
  rmdir($dir);
 }

 return (file_exists($dir) && is_dir($dir)) ? false : true;
}

$result6 = dir_del($dir);
echo gettype($result6)."\n\n".print_r($result6,1);die();
?>
```

The problem is for some reason the `gettype()` for the function result returns `NULL`. How do I have this function return true or false? Why is it returning `NULL`?

Comment: Please share a (minimal and) complete example, e.g. including the part where you are calling `gettype()`.

Comment: fyi, `return (file_exists($dir) && is_dir($dir))` is enough

Comment: @JoeDoe Older bits of code; that solved the problem, thank you!